# How to use using instead of define or other C++ feature?

Tags: c++

In my code I wrote a line like this

```
#define THREAD_OUTPUT std::cout << "Thread " << thread_index << " - saved " << url << std::endl;
```

where `thread_index` is `size_t` and `url` is `std::string`.

Of course it compiles but I want it to be more C++-like because I know that `#define` is very C-like and is not recommended for a good C++ code.

Comment: also in c this should probably be a function not a macro. Macros arent really c-style, it is just that in c++ much more than in c you can do things within the language that in ancient times were only possible with macros

Comment: just to be clear: `#define` has its applications and just like anything else it can be abused and overused. I never heard that it is not recommended to use it in c++. You use it when you need it

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 " I never heard that it is not recommended to use it in c++." Really? I hear it all the time. *Macros are evil. Don't use macros. Macros should never be used in C++.* I totally agree that they can and should be used in certain situations, but it's also the easiest mechanism to misuse and it can create craziest errors, which earned it its terrible fame. Many programmers will start screaming at the first mention of macros.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I am a bit allergic to "xy is evil" in general. Still today there are completely valid uses of macros in c++. Note for example that `__func__` was only included in the standard in c++11 ! However the cases where it makes sense to use macros are rare. What is evil is blindly abusing macros for no good reason, and imho what is really evil is using too much simplification and generalization just to arrive at a statement that everybody can remember and religiously follow just to be on the "good" side

Comment: @Yksisarvinen actually my comment was refering to "`#define` not recommended" taken literally. I hope you agree that there is nothing evil about #defining a header guard. Statements like the one of OPs are what make me believe that generalizations like "Macros are evil" do more harm than good when they come without proper and detailed explanation what actually is the evil and in what situations there is nothing "evil" at all

Comment: Looks like someone is trying to avoid some function call overhead without taking optimization into account. A compiler with a reasonable amount of optimizations turned on will examine `THREAD_OUTPUT` as a function and make a pretty good decision on whether the program would be better off if `THREAD_OUTPUT` was built into the calling function  or called as a separate function. In general, write code that is easy to read and trust the compiler to do a good job turning it into a fast program. Then test to make sure it did a good job, and if not, where so you can fix where it didn't and it matters

Comment: There's nothing C-like about *that* macro. It's wrong on so many levels, whether it shows up in C++ or C code. And it's unneeded in both C++ and C.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a type, so there is no alternative based on `using`. What you can use is a function. Here is an example using a lambda:

```
auto THREAD_OUTPUT = [&]() {
    std::cout
        << "Thread"
        << thread_index
        << " - saved "
        << url
        << std::endl;
};
```

Usage differs slightly:

```
THREAD_OUTPUT();
```

P. S. Consider whether flushing the output using
`std::endl` is necessary or useful. Not flushing may be more efficient.

Comment: It needs to be declared in the same scope as `thread_index` and `url` tho (and after these two are declared). I think function would be safer to use.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen depends on use case. A named function can be more reusable, when that is needed. Could even combine both approaches  and use the lambda to bind arguments to the function if it is used a lot from one context.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, like, a function?

```
void ThreadOutput(const std::size_t thread_index, const std::string& url)
{
    std::cout << "Thread " << thread_index << " - saved " << url << std::endl;
}
```

I'd even be tempted to make it a little more general:

```
void ThreadOutput(std::ostream& os, const std::size_t thread_index, const std::string& url)
{
    os << "Thread " << thread_index << " - saved " << url << std::endl;
}

// ThreadOutput(std::cout, 42, "https://lol.com");
```

Comment: Totally fails to reproduce the quality of the error diagnostics in case things go wrong, that cause the dead to walk among the living. Make it a template already! On a more serious note, *"East `const` ftw!"*.

Comment: Maybe the function should have 'inline' attached to it? Preventing ODR violations?

Comment: @JVApen Depends where you put it.